# C++ В чем ошибка? Как починить? Вызов виртуальной функции

Tags: c++

Дана задача исправить.

```
class A;

void fcn(A*);

class A
{
  public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
    A()
    {
        fcn(this);
    }
};

class B : A
{
    void f() { }
};

void fcn(A* p)
{
    p->f();
}

B b;

void main()
{}
```

Пробовал в функции `fcn` вызывать, `auto pb = dinamic_cast<B*>(p); pb->f();` но это не работает.

Comment: Что исправить? Чего нужно добиться?

Comment: Вот я и сам не знаю чего добиться. Дали вот такую задачу.Спросили:" В чем ошибка? Как починить?"

Comment: Знаете, без нормального ТЗ результат всегда ХЗ. Вам нужно 1. Чтоб компилировалось 2. Чтоб запускалось 3. Чтоб выполнялось именно так (например, fcn в конструкторе A и от this) - первое легко, второе - убрать вызов fcn, третье - не получится... Вобщем, вы уж сами решите, чего вы хотите. Потому что решением, например, может быть просто удаление вашего кода и написание совсем другого...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В конструкторе виртуальную функцию вызвать нельзя. Ни напрямую, ни опосредовано. Точнее можно, но типом объекта будет считаться тот, конструктор которого сейчас работает.

Это принципиальное ограничение, которое связано с тем, что поля производных классов еще не инициализированы и могут находиться в некорректном состоянии.

Comment: И функция main() в c++ должна возвращать int

Comment: @Ariox не на всех компиляторах

Comment: речь о языке, а не о компиляторах. Иначе бы компилятор был бы указан.